# How to create a new window of data graph with the click of a button in the GUI

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to create a new window when a button is clicked.

I will later have windows be created dynamically depending on inputted data.

When the button is clicked, the error code is generated as follows.

Process completed with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic

main_ui = uic.loadUiType("GUI_01.ui")[0]


class OptionWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(OptionWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        option_ui = "GUI_01.ui"
        uic.loadUi(option_ui, self)
        self.show()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets, QMainWindow, main_ui, QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked3)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked4)

    def btnclicked1(self):
        self.setGeometry(2000, 600, 800, 600)
        self.new_window.show()
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.dialog.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        cb = QComboBox()
        cb.addItem("TEMP")
        cb.addItem("Voltage")
        cb.addItem("Ampere")
        cb.addItem("pH")
        cb.activated[str].connect(self.onComboBoxChanged)
        layout.addWidget(cb)
        self.layout = layout
        self.onComboBoxChanged(cb.currentText())
        plt.show()

    def onComboBoxChanged(self, text):
        if text == "TEMP":
            self.doGraph1()
        elif text == "Voltage":
            self.doGraph2()
        elif text == "Ampere":
            self.doGraph3()
        elif text == "pH":
            self.doGraph4()

    def doGraph1(self):
        x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.fig.clear()
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        ax.set_ylabel("Temp")
        ax.set_title("TEMP")
        ax.legend()
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked2(self):
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked3(self):
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked4(self):
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_dialog = MainWindow()
    main_dialog.show()
    # window = WindowClass()
    # window.show()
    plt.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Recommendation: run your script from the CMD or console: `python /path/of/script.py` and point me to the full error message

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem because you did not include the "GUI_01.ui" file, but it is likely that the crash is due to the fact that you use the `matplotlib.pyplot` module in PyQt. These modules don't mix, pyplot has it's own event loop that clashes with the Qt event loop.

If you look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) from the MatPlotLib documentation, you'll see that they don't use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Instead they import the Figure as follows `from matplotlib.figure import Figure`. There is also no need for `plt.show`, so remove those statements

When I did this your code looks as follows...

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

main_ui = uic.loadUiType("GUI_01.ui")[0]


class OptionWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(OptionWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        option_ui = "GUI_01.ui"
        uic.loadUi(option_ui, self)
        self.show()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets, QMainWindow, main_ui, QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked3)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked4)

    def btnclicked1(self):
        self.setGeometry(2000, 600, 800, 600)
        self.new_window.show()
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.dialog.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        cb = QComboBox()
        cb.addItem("TEMP")
        cb.addItem("Voltage")
        cb.addItem("Ampere")
        cb.addItem("pH")
        cb.activated[str].connect(self.onComboBoxChanged)
        layout.addWidget(cb)
        self.layout = layout
        self.onComboBoxChanged(cb.currentText())


    def onComboBoxChanged(self, text):
        if text == "TEMP":
            self.doGraph1()
        elif text == "Voltage":
            self.doGraph2()
        elif text == "Ampere":
            self.doGraph3()
        elif text == "pH":
            self.doGraph4()

    def doGraph1(self):
        x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.fig.clear()
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        ax.set_ylabel("Temp")
        ax.set_title("TEMP")
        ax.legend()
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked2(self):
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked3(self):
        self.canvas.draw()

    def btnclicked4(self):
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_dialog = MainWindow()
    main_dialog.show()
    # window = WindowClass()
    # window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

You can give it a try. Like I said, I could not test myself because I'm missing the "GUI_01.ui" file. Therefore please make your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducible next time. Make it so that others can copy-paste-execute the code themselves and test this by doing this yourself.

Comment: Thank you.
I couldn't upload the .ui file, so I asked again using another example.

Comment: Did you try my code? In your other question you still use `plt.figure` instead of importing `Figure` from `matplotlib.figure`